Read file and translate by some rules
Task:
Read dictionary (txt file) in next format: word or expression|translation. Then application should read file for translation and translate it by this rules:

ignore case
if the searched word is not in the dictionary, then prints it without translation
if there are several suitable options, the option with the maximum length of the left part is selected, i.e. if the dictionary has translations for "look" and "look forward to" , then the most suitable option should be selected

The translation result is output to the console
Create and apply custom exceptions:
• InvalidFileFormatException
• FileFileReadException when file does not exist, no access to file, etc.
My code:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class Translator {

    public Map<String, String> getDictionary(String filePath) throws IOException, InvalidFileFormatException {
        Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filePath))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split("\\|");
                if (parts.length != 2) {
                    throw new InvalidFileFormatException("Invalid format file: " + line);
                }
                dictionary.put(parts[0].trim(), parts[1].trim());
            }
        }
        return dictionary;
    }

    public String translateText(String textFile, Map<String, String> dictionary) throws FileReadException, IOException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(textFile))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
                for (String word : words) {
                    result.append(translateWord(word, dictionary)).append(" ");
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new FileReadException("File was not found: " + textFile);
        }
        return result.toString().trim();
    }

    private String translateWord(String word, Map<String, String> dictionary) {
        String cleanedWord = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]", "");
        String translatedWord = cleanedWord;
        int maxMatchLength = 0;

        for (String key : dictionary.keySet()) {
            if (cleanedWord.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                translatedWord = dictionary.get(key);
                break;
            }

            if (cleanedWord.toLowerCase().startsWith(key.toLowerCase())) {
                if (key.length() > maxMatchLength) {
                    translatedWord = dictionary.get(key);
                    maxMatchLength = key.length();
                }
            }
        }
        return word.replaceAll(cleanedWord, translatedWord);
    }
}

public class Application {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "src/main/java/lab_2/dictionary.txt";
    private static final String INPUT_FILE = "src/main/java/lab_2/text_for_translate.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Translator translator = new Translator();
        try {
            Map<String, String> dictionary = translator.getDictionary(FILE_PATH);
            String translatedText = translator.translateText(INPUT_FILE, dictionary);
            System.out.println("Translated text:\n" + translatedText);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error while reading file: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidFileFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Invalid file format: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (FileReadException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

look|translation1
look forward to|translation2

And for text
I look forward to our meeting. it prints I translation1 forward to our meeting.
So it takes first translation, but I expect second one, because look forward to. I guess it because of split String[] words = line.split("\\s+");.
How to fix this kind of mistakes?

A rather obvious (but certainly not efficient) solution: sort dictionary by length of term, go over all terms and replace all occurrences. Not sure how you want to (or need to, this looks very much like homework) handle recursive translations, e.g. look forward to|I am happy\nI am|you are.

Hello Mark, I think the problem is in how you call translateText, if you want it to return the translation2, you must call it with look forward to, if nothing is found, with look forward and finally with look.

This is example but there is lot of space for optimization.
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ReplaceWordsFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The input text
        String text = "This is a sample text with some words to replace.";

        // The file containing word replacements
        String fileName = "replacements.txt";

        // Read the replacements from the file
        HashMap<String, String> replacements = readReplacementsFromFile(fileName);

        // Replace words in the text using the replacements
        String result = replaceWordsInText(text, replacements);

        // Print the result
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static HashMap<String, String> readReplacementsFromFile(String fileName) {
        HashMap<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Split the line into key and value by a delimiter (e.g., comma)
                String[] parts = line.split(",");
                if (parts.length == 2) {
                    // Add to the replacements map
                    replacements.put(parts[0].trim(), parts[1].trim());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return replacements;
    }

    public static String replaceWordsInText(String text, HashMap<String, String> replacements) {
        // Split the text into words using regex to handle punctuation
        String[] words = text.split("\\b");
        StringBuilder replacedText = new StringBuilder();

        for (String word : words) {
            // Check if the word exists in the HashMap
            if (replacements.containsKey(word.toLowerCase())) {
                // Replace the word with its corresponding value
                replacedText.append(replacements.get(word.toLowerCase()));
            } else {
                // Otherwise, keep the original word
                replacedText.append(word);
            }
        }

        return replacedText.toString();
    }
}

